# Failing test: Actionview template error (no route matches action: show, controller: users, id: nil) for updating user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-5, railstutorial.org

I've got a failing integration test for updating users (Rails 5). The errors are listed and pointed out in the test and 'edit.html.erb':

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersEditTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:user_one)
  end

  test "unsuccessful edit" do
    get edit_user_path(@user) #---> This is where the error is happening, line 10
    assert_template 'users/edit'
    patch user_path(@user), params: { user: { name: "", email: "not@valid", password: "not", password_confirmation: "valid" } }
    assert_template 'users/edit'
  end

end
```

The error reads:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
app/views/users/edit.html.erb:7:in
test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:10:in
```

Fixtures as follows:

```
user_one:
  name: Example One
  email: one@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>

user_two:
  name: Example Two
  email: two@exmaple.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

Edit.html.erb as follows:

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit Account") %>
<% provide(:button_text, "Save Changes") %>

<h1 class="center">Edit Account</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= render 'form', url: user_path(current_user) %> #---> The other error 
  </div>
</div>
```

_form.html.erb as follows:

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: url) do |f| %>
  <%= render "shared/error_messages", object: @user %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control'  %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.submit yield(:button_text), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>

<% end %>
```

I know that the url I'm passing to my form via 'edit' is correct because I'm getting the correct action when I check my web inspector. It reads "users/1" with a method of post, with an additional hidden field named "_method" with the value of "patch". The application functions this way but the test fails.

On line 10 in the test it's supposed to be getting the edit_user_path, but for some reason throws an error about the show action and says the id is nil. I've changed the url that I pass to be "edit_user_path(current_user)" but that gives me an error of "No route matches [PATCH] "/users/1/edit"" when I submit the form and also renders a similar test error except for listing the edit action instead of show. I've tried changing it to 'users_path(current_user)' which gets my test to PASS FINALLY, but gives me the incorrect action (action="/users.1") when viewing it in the web inspector - also won't allow me submit the form, saying: "No route matches [PATCH] "/users.1""

I'm following the latest Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl and can't imagine what I could have missed to be stuck so bad on this (day two of trying to tackle this problem). My routes in case anyone is wondering:

```
root 'static_pages#home'
get '/about' => 'static_pages#about'
get '/help' => 'static_pages#help'
get '/signup' => 'users#new'
post '/signup' => 'users#create'
get '/login' => 'sessions#new'
post '/login' => 'sessions#create'
delete '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
resources :users
```

I can get passed all of this simply by giving edit.html.erb it's own form instead of rendering the form in it's view, passing test and all. So I'll probably continue on doing that, but I know there has to be a way, or at least some stupid mistake I need to fix, for me to be able to do this the way the tutorial is.